# What are the audio-format encoders that Android and iOS have in common?

Tags: android, ios, audio, audio-recording

Furthermore, the recordings must be shared across devices (probably stored/processed on server).

Besides the formats in common, I'd like your recommendations for the right bitrate/configuration or so. I'm recording voice and I want to achieve minimum space but good/decent understanding of what people record (more or less the way WhatsApp works), so they understand each other and the file is light enough to travel relatively fast on slow connections.

I already went to this [Android chart](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html), but I know little about iOS (future development).

Comment: It's hard to suggest a bitrate/format without knowing what you're doing with the audio, and what your quality needs are.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Brad. I edited the body and hope it now gives a better idea of what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the list of supported media techonlogies on iOS in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/MediaLayer/MediaLayer.html). But it seems as if there isn't so much overlap, so you might want to go ahead and use an encoder like the open [speex](http://www.speex.org/) codec which is optimized for VoIP applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer in my another post with snippet 
MPEG_4 format and AAC encoder
[audio format for iOS and Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15871407/audio-format-for-ios-and-android/29715880#29715880)