# What format can I use to record on android and play it in ios

Tags: android, ios, base64, audio-recording, audioformat

I have tried so many different formats when I record a audio on android, that I get dizzy by just thinking about it. When I record by using .wav on ios, I can play it on android without any problem. But Im not able to play the recorded audio from a android on a ios.

I have tried to play it as a base64 and streaming by using the url. I don't know what to do play it, since nothing seems to work. But if some one just can point me in the right direction when it comes to what format I should use to record the audio on android so I can play it on ios, I would be very greatfull.

What I have so far:

```
       recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
   recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
   recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(96000);
   recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
   recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
```

but I got no idea what I should name the file I record on (like this record.mp3). Im using cordova so I have to do it when I start the recording. I have tried mp4, m4v, m4a, mp4, mp4, mpeg4 and mpeg. I have tried to record the file as a wav file as well, but then I get audio/x-wav in my base64 string.. Do I need to change the samplingRate, bitrate, outputformat or audio encoder to something else if I want to use .wav (not x-wav) and still make it work on ios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After googling this issue, it seems even the very popular app "Evernote" has the same issue, and users are gutted about it. I did come across this question here on SO:

[audio format for iOS and Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15871407/audio-format-for-ios-and-android)

They use a web service to convert the files to mp3, which works universally. I am sure you could find some way to do this without a middle man, but it should "point you in the right direction".

Hope this helps.

Cheers