# Jw player is not playing mp3 having mime type "audio/x-mpeg"

Tags: php, html, audio, ffmpeg, jwplayer

I am playing mp3 files on the JW player but i am facing a strange problem.
JW player is playing mp3 files having mime type "audio/mpeg" but it is failed to play mp3 files having mime type "audio/x-mpeg". It is such a strange problem for me because both files are mp3 JW player should play both.

I have also tried to convert mp3 file to mp3 file using ffmpeg in php but it is still producing mp3 file having mime type "audio/x-mpeg".
 exec(ffmpeg -i $input_file -vn -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 192k -f mp3 output.mp3)

one thing i need to mention that this file type is generating from ios app.
I am stuck from 2 days in this issue. Your help would be really appreciated . 
Thanks

Comment: Show the complete log/console output from the `ffmpeg` command.

Comment: why `audio/x-mpeg` mime type ?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I am executing ffmpeg command in php as i have posted it in the answer . I am not executing ffpmeg command on console.

Comment: @Hitesh i am recording audio on ios app and its audio is generating in mp3 and its mime type is audio/x-mpeg . I have tried to convert this mp3 using ffmpeg but still it is generating mp3 having mime type audio/x-mpeg. I need mp3 file having mime type audio/mpeg to play in jw palyer. While when i record audio on the same apple device using browser this file is playing normally after converting from ffmpeg.

Comment: Yes, that is obvious, but either way you are executing the `ffmpeg` binary and it will output useful info to stderr. You should provide this info.

Comment: where i can find stderr ?

Comment: I need to convert mime type . I can't change any coding of jw player integration.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep the mp3 with supported mime type.

Jwplayer does not support audio/x-mpeg format. Check [here](http://dev.powered-by-haiku.co.uk/jw-video/jwplayer/v6.b/jw6-beta/doc/media.html)

Update:

1) [audio format for iOS and Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15871407/audio-format-for-ios-and-android)

2) [What are the audio-format encoders that Android and iOS have in common?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213158/what-are-the-audio-format-encoders-that-android-and-ios-have-in-common?rq=1)

Hope this helps

Comment: Is there any player that can be integrated in all type of devices on all platform and can run their generated audio/video files because i have app,website and i need to run files on different platforms , browsers etc.

Comment: added two links please check them if it is helpful